# Jpgraph wont change colors on my barplot

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm just getting started with jpgraph and XAMPP I was looking to make a barplot.
As I was reading some articles on the web it said you could pass in an array of colors to setfillcolor so that each bar would be a different color. However whenever I pass it color the graph won't change from its default color of light blue.

The graph respond s to changes in data but not changes to color.
I tried with an accumulated bar graph example and that seems to be color responsive.

I'm not sure how to diagnose a problem like this. Help please!

Code Below(Example from the Jpgraph documentation with color changed from orange to #B0C4DE [orange from the original example doesn't show up]):

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."\lib\jpgraph-3.5.0b1\src\jpgraph.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."\lib\jpgraph-3.5.0b1\src\jpgraph_line.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."\lib\jpgraph-3.5.0b1\src\jpgraph_bar.php");

$datay=array(2,3,5,25,15,6,3);
$datax=array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul');

// Size of graph
$width=400;
$height=500;

// Set the basic parameters of the graph
$graph = new Graph($width,$height,'auto');
$graph->SetScale('textlin');

// Rotate graph 90 degrees and set margin
$graph->Set90AndMargin(50,20,50,30);

// Nice shadow
$graph->SetShadow();

// Setup title
$graph->title->Set('Horizontal bar graph ex 1');
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_VERDANA,FS_BOLD,14);

// Setup X-axis
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($datax);
$graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_VERDANA,FS_NORMAL,12);

// Some extra margin looks nicer
$graph->xaxis->SetLabelMargin(10);

// Label align for X-axis
$graph->xaxis->SetLabelAlign('right','center');

// Add some grace to y-axis so the bars doesn't go
// all the way to the end of the plot area
$graph->yaxis->scale->SetGrace(20);

// We don't want to display Y-axis
$graph->yaxis->Hide();

// Now create a bar pot
$bplot = new BarPlot($datay);

$bplot->SetFillColor("#B0C4DE");
//  ALSO tried:
//  $bplot->SetColor(array("red","green","blue","gray"));
$bplot->SetShadow();

//You can change the width of the bars if you like
//$bplot->SetWidth(0.5);

// We want to display the value of each bar at the top
$bplot->value->Show();
$bplot->value->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,12);
$bplot->value->SetAlign('left','center');
$bplot->value->SetColor('black','darkred');
$bplot->value->SetFormat('%.1f mkr');

// Add the bar to the graph
$graph->Add($bplot);

// .. and stroke the graph
$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Nothing concerning the bar formatting is taken into account (value, color, ...). but it's worling fine with line plots

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem, the solution I found is to define the formatting after the BarPlot class initialization

```
$bplot = new BarPlot($datay);
$graph->Add($bplot);
$bplot->value->Show();
$bplot->value->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,12);
$bplot->value->SetAlign('left','center');
$bplot->value->SetColor('black','darkred');
$bplot->value->SetFormat('%.1f mkr');
```

Solution found [here](http://webdeveloperoddities.blogspot.com/2010/10/jpgraph-cannot-change-line-colour-or.html)

Comment: I had same problem with the LinePlot class, this seems to solve it for that class as well.

Comment: Is there a way to set color not only value but also for the bar itself. So that negative bars have different color than positive ones?

Answer (score 12):

I have the same problem, and this is my solution: just add "ClearTheme()",like this:

```
     $graph = new Graph(310,200); 
     $graph->ClearTheme();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the `Add()` using the Theme default settings. There are two solutions

1. Add plot before applying settings
2. Remove Theme `$graph->graph_theme = null;` after `$graph->SetScale()` or adjust the theme

**Source:** [/docs/chunkhtml/ch29.html - Part VII. Theme Class](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch29.html)

I recently dug into this as my legend was also not displaying correctly **[JpGraph: How to control x/y offset, margins and color in v3.5.0b1 when using AccBarPlot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474088/jpgraph-how-to-control-x-y-offset-margins-and-color-in-v3-5-0b1-when-using-acc)**