# JpGraph: How to control x/y offset, margins and color in v3.5.0b1 when using AccBarPlot?

Tags: php, graph, gd, jpgraph, symfony-1.2

## A little background

I am attempting to migrate a project built with Symfony 1.2 from one server to another. One of the functions of the project is to build a graph (originally done with JpGraph 2.3.5).

**The graph does not display as intended without modifications to the code and am looking for some insight on what I might be overlooking.** *Images are linked due to not having enough points to post.* **[Graph Image Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTWna.jpg)**

The following graph is what is generated by the code block below
[image]

```
<?php
    public function Graph($section) {
        $report = $section->getReport();
        $this->crews = array();
        foreach ($section->getCrews() as $crew) {
            $this->crews[$crew->getId()] = $crew;
        };

        # get the data
        $nextDayValues = $section->getNextDayValues();
        $nextDayValueLabels = $section->getNextDayValueLabels();

        $max_y = max($nextDayValues) < 7 ? 7 : max($nextDayValues);
        $this->crew_order = array_keys($nextDayValues);
        $this->summary = $this->getSummary();
        $this->bar_count = count($this->crews) + count($this->summary);

        $left    = 200;
        $right   =  30;
        $top     =  60;
        $bottom  =  80;
        $width   = 640;
        $height  = $top + $bottom + ($this->bar_count * 30 );

        $x_unit = $this->bar_count / ($height - $top - $bottom);
        $y_unit = $max_y / ($width - $left - $right);

        $csim_targets = array();
        $csim_alts = array();
        $bar_data = array();
        $max_days = 0;

        foreach ($this->crew_order as $i => $crew_id) {
            $csim_targets[$i] = url_for('units/index?crew_id='.$crew_id);
            $csim_alts[$i] = sprintf("Units for %s",
              $this->crews[$crew_id]->getCrew());

            # figure out the maximum y value
            $nextDayUnitsList = $this->crews[$crew_id]->getNextDayUnitsList();
            $units_array[$crew_id] = $nextDayUnitsList;

            if (count($nextDayUnitsList) > $this->max_days) {
                $this->max_days = count($nextDayUnitsList);
            };
        };

        $bg_values = array_values($nextDayValues);
        foreach ($this->summary as $summary) {
            array_push ($bg_values, $summary['value']);
        };

        $bg_bar = new BarPlot($bg_values);
        $bg_bar->SetCSIMTargets($csim_targets, $csim_alts);
        $bg_bar->SetNoFill(true);

        $fg_bars = $this->getFgBars($units_array);
        $fg_bar = new AccBarPlot($fg_bars);
        $fg_bar->SetFillColor('black');

        # initialize the graph
        $graph = new Graph($width, $height, 'auto');
        $graph->SetScale('textlin', 0, $max_y, 0, $this->bar_count);
        $graph->Set90AndMargin($left, $right, $top, $bottom);
        $graph->SetMarginColor('white');
        $graph->SetFrame(false);

        $graph->Add($fg_bar);
        $graph->Add($bg_bar);

        # add text labels
        foreach ($this->crew_order as $i => $crew_id) {
            $label = $this->value_label(
                $nextDayValueLabels[$crew_id],
                $i, $nextDayValues[$crew_id],
                10 * $x_unit, 5 * $y_unit
            );
            $graph->AddText($label);
        };

        foreach ($this->summary as $i => $summary) {
            $label = $this->value_label(
                $summary['value'],
                $i, $summary['value'],
                10 * $x_unit, 5 * $y_unit
            );
            $graph->AddText($label);
        };

        # add title
        $graph->title->Set(sprintf("%s - %s", $report->getName(),
          $section->getName()));
        $graph->title->SetFont(FF_VERDANA,FS_BOLD, 12);
        $graph->title->SetMargin(10);

        # add subtitle
        $graph->subtitle->Set(date('d-M-Y g:ia'));
        $graph->subtitle->SetFont(FF_VERDANA,FS_BOLD, 8);

        # configure x-axis
        $graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_VERDANA, FS_NORMAL, 8);
        $graph->xaxis->SetLabelAlign('right', 'center');
        $graph->xaxis->SetLabelFormatCallback(array($this, 'x_axis_label'));
        $graph->xaxis->scale->ticks->Set(1, 0);

        # configure y-axis
        $graph->yaxis->SetFont(FF_VERDANA, FS_NORMAL, 8);
        $graph->yaxis->SetLabelAlign('center', 'top');
        $graph->yaxis->SetLabelAngle(45);
        $graph->yaxis->SetLabelFormatCallback(array($this, 'y_axis_label'));
        $graph->yaxis->SetPos('max');
        $graph->yaxis->SetLabelSide(SIDE_RIGHT);
        $graph->yaxis->SetTickSide(SIDE_LEFT);

        if (max($nextDayValues) > 28) {
            $graph->yaxis->scale->ticks->Set(7, 1);
        } else {
            $graph->yaxis->scale->ticks->Set(1, 1);
        };

        # configure legend
        $graph->legend->SetAbsPos(5, $height - 5, "left", "bottom");
        $graph->legend->SetColumns(count($this->legend));
        $graph->legend->SetFillColor('white');
        $graph->legend->SetShadow(false);

        $graph->SetImgFormat('png');

        return $graph;
    }

    private function getFgBars($units_array) {
        # initialize fg_bar data
        $empty_crews = array_fill_keys(array_keys($this->crew_order),0);

        # add segment bars
        foreach ($this->summary as $summary) {
            $empty_crews[] = 0;
        };

        $empty_segment = array();
        foreach (array_keys($this->legend_colors) as $status) {
            $empty_segment[$status] = $empty_crews;
        };

        $segments = array();
        for ($day = 0; $day < $this->max_days; $day++) {
            foreach (array_keys($empty_segment) as $status) {
                $segment = $empty_segment;
                foreach ($this->crew_order as $i => $crew_id) {
                    $nextDayUnitsList = $units_array[$crew_id];
                    if ($day + 1 < count($nextDayUnitsList)) {
                        $units = $nextDayUnitsList[$day];
                        $units_status = $units->getNextDayStatus();
                        $segment[$units_status][$i] = 1;
                    } elseif ($day + 1 == count($nextDayUnitsList)) {
                        $units = $nextDayUnitsList[$day];
                        $units_status = $units->getNextDayStatus();
                        $avail = $units->getUsedRatio();
                        $segment[$units_status][$i] = $avail;
                    } elseif ($day + 1 > count($nextDayUnitsList)) {
                        $segment[$units_status][$i] = 0;
                    };
                };
            };

            foreach ($this->summary as $i => $summary) {
                $diff = $summary['value'] - $day;
                if ($diff >= 1) {
                    $segment['summary'][$i] = 1;
                } elseif ($diff >= 0) {
                    $segment['summary'][$i] = $diff;
                } else {
                    $segment['summary'][$i] = 0;
                }
            };
            $segments[$day] = $segment;
        };

        # create legend
        $fg_bars = array();
        foreach (array_keys($empty_segment) as $status) {
            $fg_bar = new BarPlot($empty_crews);
            $fg_bar->setFillColor($this->legend_colors[$status]);

            if ($status <> 'summary') {
                $fg_bar->SetLegend($this->legend[$status]);
            };
            $fg_bars[] = $fg_bar;
        };

        # add segments
        foreach ($segments as $day => $segment) {
            foreach (array_keys($empty_segment) as $status) {
                $fg_bar = new BarPlot($segment[$status]);
                $fg_bar->setColor($this->legend_colors[$status]);
                $fg_bar->setFillColor($this->legend_colors[$status]);
                $fg_bars[] = $fg_bar;
            };
        };
        return $fg_bars;
    }
?>
```

Now the same graph on the new server using JpGraph 2.3.5 or JpGraph 3.5.0b1
[image]

### A few problems can be seen:

1. Colours are not applied
2. x/y coord are offset (margins?)
3. scale is off
4. scale ticks are also removed

I am aware that to correct the colour you place `$graph->Add($x);` before modifying the properties. As such I had to move the code within the `getFgBars()` into `Graph()`.

Which is documented in the manual under **[/docs/chunkhtml/ch29s02.html](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch29s02.html)**

With revising the code I broke apart the FgBars into `$fg_bars[]` & `$lg_bars[]` being the foreground data (color) & Legend bar.
[image]

If I remove the legend bar, the graph is displayed as intended.
[image]

## **Question:**

What would be causing the margin / scale to go wonkey when adding on a second `AccBarPlot()`?

## **Solution:**

Remove default theme. `$graph->graph_theme = null;` will restore both colour & margins without requiring to rewrite any code.

```
    # initialize the graph
    $graph = new Graph($width, $height, 'auto');
    $graph->SetScale('textlin', 0, $max_y, 0, $this->bar_count);
    $graph->Set90AndMargin($left, $right, $top, $bottom);
    $graph->SetMarginColor('white');
    $graph->SetFrame(false);
    $graph->graph_theme = null;
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## **Solution:**

Remove default theme. `$graph->graph_theme = null;` after initalizing `Graph()` will restore both colour & margins without requiring to rewrite any code.

```
    # initialize the graph
    $graph = new Graph($width, $height, 'auto');
    $graph->SetScale('textlin', 0, $max_y, 0, $this->bar_count);
    $graph->Set90AndMargin($left, $right, $top, $bottom);
    $graph->SetMarginColor('white');
    $graph->SetFrame(false);
    $graph->graph_theme = null;
```

[image]

## Resources:

[/docs/chunkhtml/ch29.html#id2619634](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch29.html#id2619634) - The order of SetTheme() and changing settings
[/docs/chunkhtml/ch29s02.html](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch29s02.html) - Changing the display settings of line/bar graphs